# Is it possible to catch and handle SSH connection errors in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to upgrade the software of a network appliance. After the installation, I reboot the box, and I use ansible's `wait_for` module to wait for SSH to come back up, and then I use a do-until loop to run a command and wait for a particular output string:

```
- name: Wait for box to come back up
  local_action: wait_for host={{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}
      search_regex=OpenSSH
      port=22
      delay=20
      timeout=600

- name: Wait for box to enter the running phase
  shell: tmsh -q -a show sys mcp
  changed_when: False
  ignore_errors: True
  register: mcp_wait
  until: mcp_wait.stdout.find("running") != -1
  retries: 1200
  delay: 10
```

The problem is, for some software upgrades, the appliance will reboot twice. It comes up, SSH starts, then it installs some firmware updates, and reboots a second time. This causes my playbook to error out. The `wait_for` task succeeds, and then the do-until task starts looping, but the second reboot of the box causes this do-until command to fail with an `SSH Connection timed out` error.

```
TASK: [appliance | Wait for box to come back up] ******************************* 
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE wait_for host=10.1.1.1 search_regex=OpenSSH port=22 delay=20 timeout=600
ok: [10.1.1.1 -> 127.0.0.1] => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 93, "path": null, "port": 22, "search_regex": "OpenSSH", "state": "started"}

TASK: [appliance | Wait for box to enter the running phase] *********************************** 
<10.1.1.1> REMOTE_MODULE command tmsh -q -a show sys mcp #USE_SHELL
Result from run 1 is: {'cmd': 'tmsh -q -a show sys mcp', 'end': '2015-10-01 10:58:27.025674', 'stdout': u'', 'changed': True, 'attempts': 1, 'start': '2015-10-01 10:58:26.928485', 'delta': '0:00:00.097189', 'stderr': 'Cannot connect to mcpd.', 'rc': 1, 'warnings': []}
--snipped repeated lines--
<10.1.1.1> REMOTE_MODULE command tmsh -q -a show sys mcp #USE_SHELL
fatal: [10.1.1.1] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.1 port 22: Connection timed out
    while connecting to 10.1.1.1:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/loudsong/play.retry

10.1.1.1               : ok=25   changed=4    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

So what I really need is to keep my task `Wait for box to enter the running phase` looping until it eventually succeeds, regardless if the target device is completely unreachable.  I'd also be happy if I could catch the SSH connection error, and then execute another `wait_for` task to wait for the box to finish the second reboot cycle. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any programmatic way of knowing that the box is about to be restarted for a second time?

Comment: Well, if I tail the log messages, I can see that the firmware updates are occurring, and thus a second reboot will occur soon. I suppose then I might be able to wait until it goes unreachable again, and then start polling for the second time. Wasn't exactly what I wanted to do :-/

Comment: I was more thinking about whether it logged anything to anywhere when it makes the decision to reboot but before actually rebooting?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I ended up with was to convert the action to a local action instead:

```
- name: Wait till MCP enters the running phase
  local_action: command sshpass -p "{{ansible_ssh_pass|default('')}}" ssh root@{{inventory_hostname}} tmsh -q -a show sys mcp
  changed_when: False
  register: mcp_wait
  until: mcp_wait.stdout.find("running") != -1
  retries: 300
```

This way, the task will keep looping, attempting to execute the command remotely over SSH until it finds "running" in stdout, even if the box goes unreachable.

Incidentally, I did see that Ansible allows you to write callbacks, which appear to let you catch an 'unreachable' event. Though I didn't pursue this enough to be sure that it would have solved the problem I described in my question. See function v2_runner_on_unreachable():
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py

Comment: I tried this with ansible 2.9 and I still get fatal error when host OS is unreachable.